# Setting up a spring boot project combined with react

Tags: jquery, spring, reactjs, spring-boot

I'm planning on building this application in spring boot & reactjs. I was wondering what a good setup would be. After some research I concluded there are 3 ways I think I could go.

1) Build an API in spring boot(Backend) and start a second project in ReactJS (Frontend). This would fully disconnect the frontend of the backend, which in theory sounds nice. But it seems like a lot more work.

2) Render the views on the backend and use React to progressive enhance + build the dynamic parts on the page. (I don't know if this is possible)

3) Render the views on the backend and throw out React and use jquery like a traditional project.

Personally I'm leaning to the second option. It would save us lots of development time and we can still use React for the highly dynamic parts of the website. The only problem is that I don't know if this is even possible. All of the information I seem to find is to have full React applications.

Do you guys have an opinion on this or do you have some recommended approaches?

Comment: Hi, I'm facing a similar issue in my actual project. Our approach is going to be like the #1. Which means that React will ask for the data to the Backend (Spring) and render the components as requested. This topic sounds really interesting to me so any comments about different approaches will be nice!

Comment: Having disconnected backend and frontend really helps in my experience. It is also easier to find a developer to help with one of the parts than somebody that masters both.

Answer (score 1):

I have made an application using reactjs and spring boot.

1.)As you mentioned handling both frontend and backend in different project would be a hectic job but it is a better practice as it seperates back end from front end and you do not have to deploy your application again and again to render updated changes

2.)I have done it using second approach by using pusher api.I render data through react only by making an ajax call to spring controller and fetching data in json.

but there is an issue in second approach as i need to compile webpack and deploy whole application again to see updated changes on my page.

but yes it is not a difficult job using second approach.You can go for it

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1 is the only wise solution if maintainability and scalability are something that you care about. (If it is really small scale project, ignore this)

### Reasons

1. "Separation of concerns" or rather "do one thing and one thing well" --> Maintainability
2. Good Javascript-land developers may not be good backend programmers and vice-versa. You don't really have to hire "Fullstack" Developers (BTW, let me tell you a secret, "Fullstack" is a pipe-dream :))
3. If you want to go serverless - It's easy - Front end's nodeJs/nginx can be replaced with AWS S3 (GCP equivalent - cloud storage) and backend can be replaced with AWS lambda (GCP equivalent - Cloud Functions).